# Google Analytics bit code release

Tags: ios, google-analytics, bitcode

When I create a new project enable bit code YES works fine but When I try to update my old project which was enable bit code NO it doesn't work. What I have done:
I have loaded new Google Analytics and frameworks again. Changed enable bit code to YES. When I run in simulator it works fine but when I run in device it fails and says "ld: -bundle and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current Google/Analytics pod does not support Bitcode.  The GoogleAnalytics pod, however, does.  Unfortunately there actually is a difference.

Read this thread for more information.

[Google Developers](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=671#makechanges)